# How can I get the list of movies by a director from dbpedia using sparql query

Tags: python, sparql, rdflib

I have been facing a great deal of difficulty trying to write a python code that will return the list of movies by the director called Francis Ford Coppola. Below is a good that I have so far your assistance will be greatly appreciated. I have also added a picture of the list movie, I hope it helps.

```
director = 'http://dbpedia.org/resource/Francis_Ford_Coppola'
director_graph = rdflib.Graph()
director_graph.load(URIRef(director))
movie_list_query = """PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/> PREFIX dbr: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/> SELECT ?x WHERE {?x a dbo:Film; dbo:director dbr:Francis_Ford_Coppola}"""
query = director_graph.query(movie_list_query)
print(dir(query))
for x in query:
    print(x)
```

[image]

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“Show me how to solve this coding problem” is not a Stack Overflow issue.  We expect you to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.
Accessing the elements of a common data structure, is covered in the documentation for that package.

Comment: @Prune I made an attempt, have a look at the code that I added the code returns an empty is thats why I turned to developers here to show me where Im going wrong

Comment: that's not gonna work how you're doing. Either you have to query the DBpedia SPARQL endpoint or you have to load more data. Currently, all you load is the data for a single entity. It is equivalent to `https://dbpedia.org/data/Francis_Ford_Coppola.nt` - but this does only contain the direct incoming and outgoing edges of `Francis_Ford_Coppola` - the other information about the connected entities is missing, in your case the ?s rdf:type dbo:Film` is indeed missing as this is information about the film entities connected to Coppola, i.e. one hop more in the graph

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using an RDFlib `Store` to connect to wrap the DBpedia SPARQL endpoint like this: https://github.com/RDFLib/rdflib/blob/master/examples/sparqlstore_example.py#L13